# Oracle 9.2.0.1 Client и Windows 2008 Server x64

Tags: oracle

Не могу поставить клиента Oracle 9.2.0.1 Client на WinServ 2008, пишет нет связи с Оракл, в службы заглянул там нет ЛИСТИНЕРА, как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы ставите oracle клиента, то значит c этой машины будете обращаться к серверу. Служба листенера запускается на сервере обычно на порту 5021.Для доступа к Oracle в специальном файле tnsnames.ora указывают адрес этого сервера и другие данные о нем (имя инстанса, номер порта листенера).Уточните Вашу ошибку "Нет связи с Оracle", тогда можно ответить точнее. Если в файле tnsnames.ora есть введенные Вами данные, напишите.

Answer (score 0):

Надо установить слушателя!